# How to set the data table into an array(parse data table in array)?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

*We have table:*

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>01050.ru</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>TEMPP</td>
  <td>2013-03-22</td>
  <td>2014-04-22</td>
 </tr> <tr>
  <td>01230.ru</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>TEMPP</td>
  <td>2013-03-22</td>
  <td>2014-04-22</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

*I would like make array with data this table, that get next result:*

```
array(

[1]=>array(
    [1]=>'01050.ru',
    [2]=>'0',
    [3]=>'0',
    [4]=>'0',
    [5]=>'0',
    [6]=>'0',
    [7]=>'0',
    [8]=>'0',
    [9]=>'TEMPP',
    [10]=>'2013-03-22',
    [11]=>'2014-04-22',

),
[2]=>array(
    [1]=>'01230.ru',
    [2]=>'0',
    [3]=>'0',
    [4]=>'0',
    [5]=>'0',
    [6]=>'0',
    [7]=>'0',
    [8]=>'0',
    [9]=>'TEMPP',
    [10]=>'2013-03-22',
    [11]=>'2014-04-22',

)
)
```

*Tell me please how get this result?*

*P.S.: sorry for bad show arrays.*

Comment: In other words you want to parse html table to array?

Comment: your question is not clear! what is this data table? how you got it? its from PHP file? explain please

Comment: @hindmost yes, you are right

Comment: @dlyaza yes, table in php file. for example `$table = '...'; //where ... code table`

Comment: You can use Simple HTML DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple HTML DOM Parser. Somehow like this:

```
$table = str_get_html($table_html);
$a_result = array();
foreach ($table->find('tr') as $tr) {
    $a_row = array();
    foreach ($tr->find('td') as $td) $a_row[] = $td->innertext;
    $a_result[] = $a_row;
}
print_r($a_result);
```